# Trying to add "-" minus & "+" plus buttons next to the TextView but it automatically puts it below the TextView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is the code that I have written so far for each card that I am doing for a carousel. Also, not sure whether to use ImageButton or Button as I am trying to do a '-'/'+' button for users to press on.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="22dp">
    
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- ImageView for images placed above the text-->
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageIv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <!-- TextView is right below the image-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/flavorTv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Flavor 1"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
    <!-- Trying to place the button on the same row as the TextView-->
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
    
    
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

[image]

Comment: Because you have them in a LinearLayout set to vertical.  That puts them all one below the other.  The LinearLayout isn't going to suddenly change directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your inner LinearLayout with a ConstraintLayout so you will be able to position views depending on constraints you define. Like in the following example:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="22dp">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- ImageView for images placed above the text-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageIv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
            <!-- TextView is right below the image-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/flavorTv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Flavor 1"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageIv"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
            <!-- Trying to place the button on the same row as the TextView-->
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageIv"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/flavorTv"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

wrap textview and image inside linear layout:

```
 <!-- TextView is right below the image-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/flavorTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Flavor 1"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
            <!-- Trying to place the button on the same row as the TextView-->
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Adjust margin, padding as per your requirements.

Option 2:

use drawable with textview:

```
  <TextView
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/cald"
                android:id="@+id/flavorTv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Flavor 1"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
```

remove the ImageButton, use an icon and set textview.setOnviewClickListener to add code for image navigation

Comment: Thank you so much it has been solved already!